# Requirejs optimizer + git developement files in remote branch

Tags: git, github, requirejs, gitignore

I'm using requirejs optimizer to uglify and minify my CSS and JS files on a project. This project uses git with the following architecture:

- (local) branch dev
- (local) branch master
- (remote) branch origin

This is the way I work:

1. I develop, debug and add functionnalities on the 'dev' branch.
2. When it works, I commit in 'dev', switch to 'master' and I merge with dev
3. In 'master' branch  I minify and uglify my folders '/css' and '/js' thanks
   to requirejs optimizer and resulting files are in a folder 'build/js' and 'build/css'. Then I commit my new build files in 'master'
4. I push to the server with the command `git push origin master`

The problem here is that obvisouly all files are pushed to the remote branch, the "build" folders but also the '/css' and '/js' folders containing all my development files (with comments and not uglified), while I don't want them to be pushed.

I would like the **developments files to remain in the git scope of 'dev' and 'master'** (for when I work on them) but I would like **them to be ignored when I push to the remote branch origin**.

I have tried to cache them with `git rm -r --cached css` and to add them in `.gitignore` but this means that when I work on them on dev and I merge with 'master' they are not taken into account by git anymore and this is a problem.
Also some files in 'dev' and 'master' are not exactly the same due to local configurations vs. released configuration - especially js files (website address, facebook IDs, etc.)

Would you know how to tackle this?

Thanks!

Paganel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches. In some of them, you don't have built scripts under version control. In others, the deploy doesn't have a full clone of the repo.

Although hacky, one approach would be to use Grunt or gulp to run a batch of tasks that include your minification but does also checkout a production branch. Fabric or even bash are enough for this. E.g

```
r.js --params a b c d
git add -all
git commit -am "build task"
git push origin master
git checkout production
git checkout master js-build
git rm -r --cached js/
git add js-build/
git commit -am "cleaning sources"
git push -f origin production
git checkout master
```

Tools like gitflow deal like that when you call git hf release commands.

Keep in mind that origin isn't a branch. It is a remote. Pushing to origin master usually means "push local master to origin master".

Also, if you're aiming to avoid a third party seeing the source, any cloned repo does still have the source in its refs. You can prevent web access to the .git folder but any person with shell (or ftp/sftp) access can freely figure out any file that was part of any branch at any point of history.